# Custom HighRepJobPolicy in Google App Engine development server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using a custom HighRepJobPolicy in the App Engine development server. The same class works fine when I use it in my unit tests:

```
LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig datastoreConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
datastoreConfig.setAlternateHighRepJobPolicyClass(CustomHighRepJobPolicy.class);
```

But when I try to use this class in the Java development server by adding the JVM tag

```
-Ddatastore.high_replication_job_policy_class=foo.bar.CustomHighRepJobPolicy
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.CustomHighRepJobPolicy
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:87)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.initHighRepJobPolicy(LocalDatastoreService.java:426)
        ... 66 more
```

Is this expected to work, or has anyone else tried this before? I ask because I could not find any information about this via Google, and the App Engine [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore) only mention the DefaultHighRepJobPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like you were early to the party](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests) :

```
public class LocalCustomPolicyHighRepDatastoreTest {
    private static final class CustomHighRepJobPolicy implements HighRepJobPolicy {
        static int count = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean shouldApplyNewJob(Key entityGroup) {
            // every other new job fails to apply
            return count++ % 2 == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRollForwardExistingJob(Key entityGroup) {
            // every other existing job fails to apply
            return count++ % 2 == 0;
        }
    }

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
           .setAlternateHighRepJobPolicyClass(CustomHighRepJobPolicy.class));

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEventuallyConsistentGlobalQueryResult() {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        ds.put(new Entity("yam")); // applies
        ds.put(new Entity("yam")); // does not apply
        // first global query only sees the first Entity
        assertEquals(1, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
        // second global query sees both Entities because we "groom" (attempt to
        // apply unapplied jobs) after every query
        assertEquals(2, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
    }
}
```